# Is it necessary to use CURL Libraries in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

Currently I am developing project on CURL, I am literally confused
 between using or using not CURL Libraries. If Yes, then why should I
 use? If I use native Curl functions in CI just like a core PHP, it
 works like a charm. Is it necessary to use Third-Party Library?

Comment: It's necessary? No.

Comment: no no need to add curl library

Comment: It is not a requirement, but a pre-made library can help make things a lot easier and speed up production.